# Compilation error in code snippet by lift-json 3.0.1 to convert json arrays into comma-separated-strings

Tags: json, scala, lift-json

I'm trying to consume a json-formatted text and convert it into xml. I'm utilising [lift-json](https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json) for that matter. According to the lift-json documentation [here](https://www.liftweb.net/api/25/api/net/liftweb/json/Xml$.html) (`def toXml`), I should be able to convert elements of json arrays into comma separated strings using:

```
toXml(json map {
  case JField("nums",JArray(ns)) => JField("nums",JString(ns.map(_.values).mkString(",")))
  case x => x
})
```

So I wrote the following code:

```
case work: ActiveMQTextMessage => 
  println("work.getText: " + work.getText)
  val workAsJson: JValue = parse(work.getText)
  val processedArraysJson = workAsJson map {
    case JField(label, JArray(ns)) => JField(label, JString(ns.map(_.values).mkString(",")))
    case x => x
  }
  val workAsXml: scala.xml.NodeSeq = toXml(processedArraysJson)
```

But for some reason it doesn't compile.

It reports two errors:

```
Error:(55, 14) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : net.liftweb.json.JsonAST.JField
 required: net.liftweb.json.JsonAST.JValue
        case JField(label, JArray(ns)) => JField(label, JString(ns.map(_.values).mkString(",")))

Error:(55, 49) type mismatch;
 found   : net.liftweb.json.JsonAST.JField
 required: net.liftweb.json.JsonAST.JValue
        case JField(label, JArray(ns)) => JField(label, JString(ns.map(_.values).mkString(",")))
```

Notice, version of lift-json I'm using is:

```
"net.liftweb" % "lift-json_2.12" % "3.0.1"
```

with scala 2.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that Lift 3.0 changed some inconsistencies in lift-json's usage of `map`. `JField` was once a `JValue`, but that is no longer the case as it didn't make conceptual sense. To map over fields, you now must use `mapField`. Changing `map` to `mapField` in the above code should be enough, and I've [issued a PR to update the documentation](https://github.com/lift/framework/pull/1884) as well.

(Note that you'll usually get quicker answers on [the Lift Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/liftweb).)

Comment: many thanks Antonio, that worked, I'll keep your note in mind for next times.

Comment: No problem! And sorry for taking so long… I spotted this question a few weeks ago but forgot to post a response :(